# How to use get_close_matches in the code below?

Tags: python

I am trying to build a interactive dictionary. I am using get close matches to return results for typos. Can someone point out what is wrong with my elif? I am new to python

```
import mysql.connector
import difflib
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
from difflib import get_close_matches

con = mysql.connector.connect(
user = "ardit700_student",
password = "ardit700_student",
host = "108.167.140.122",
database = "ardit700_pm1database",
)

word = input("Enter the word: ")
cursor = con.cursor() #create object to navigate through the page
query = cursor.execute("select * from Dictionary where Expression = '%s'" %word) #use cursor to execute the query
results = cursor.fetchall() # store all the results in a variable

if results:
    for result in results:
        print(result)
elif get_close_matches(word, cursor.stored_results()):
    print(results)
else:
    print("word not found")
```

Comment: if `results` is non empty the `elif get_close_matches(word, cursor.stored_results())` is never going to execute.

Answer (score 1):

To make it work correctly you can use list comprehension and get a list of the keys from the db.

```
query1 = cursor.execute("SELECT Expression from Dictionary")
keys = [b[0] for b in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Then when you use get_close_matches() you'll do:

```
get_close_matches(word, keys)
```